# How to get Manufacturer dropdown in custom module edit form?

Tags: magento

I want to add images for each brand, for that i have created a module. in module's edit form i want a manufacturer dropdown list so i can assign image to the particular manufacturer/brand.

its my code for the edit form location:

app/code/local/Root/Brand/Block/Adminhtml/Brand/Edit/Tab/form.php

```
 $fieldset->addField('title', 'select', array(
    'name' => 'title',
    'label' => 'Brand',
    'values' => Mage::getUrl('catalogsearch/advanced/result', array(
    'brand' => $option['value']
    ))
 ));
 $fieldset->addField('filename', 'image', array(
    'label' => Mage::helper('brand')->__('Brand Image') ,
    'required' => false,
    'name' => 'filename',
    'note' => '(*.jpg, *.png, *.gif)'
 ));
```

Comment: You cant get in that way. You need to renderer all the manufacturer Names by using renderer class

Comment: @PavanKumar thank you, Can You explain it more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'manufacturer');
         //here, "brandname" is the attribute_code
     $allOptions = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(true, true);
     $fieldset->addField('title', 'select', array(
      'label'     => Mage::helper('brand')->__('Brand Name'),
      'name'    => 'title',
      'values'   => $allOptions
  ));
```